# Figuring out variable pairs in an inequality

Tags: elementary-number-theory, inequality, diophantine-equations, integers, euclidean-algorithm

Let $x$ and $y$ be positive integers such that

> $45 < 8x + 5y < 60$

How many $(x,y)$ pairs can be found? 
(Ans: 16) 
Of course, there is a way to write it one by one. On the other hand there is a geometrical solution which is really nice but I don't want that. Can we write create and algebraic equation system that helps us to find the pairs. One of my friends talked my about the Diophantine equations, I don't have enough information about that so I don't know if it helps. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score -1):

Consider the diophantine equation $$8x+5y=k$$ and choose one solution, say $(x,y)=(1,1)$, so we have $$\begin{cases} 8x+5y=k\\8*1+5*1=13\end{cases}\\$$ Take the difference $$8(x-1)+5(y-1)=k-13$$ We need $$45\lt{k-13}\lt60 \iff 58 \lt{k}\lt73$$
We have then $73-58=15$ solutions which finally gives with the solution $(x,y)=(1,1)$ the required 16 solutions.

NOTE.-The solution $(x,y)=(1,1)$ is a solution of the diophantine equation without restrictions but it must be consider in final computing the total of solutions after the condition $45\lt{k-13}\lt60$ (it is actually an auxiliary solution).

Comment: I didn't find your answer consistent. Because we defined 8x + 5y = k and we know k must be 45 < k < 60 but at the and of your solution we get 58 < k < 73.

Comment: This is a method to parameterized all the integer solutions of $8x+5y=z$. Note the auxiliary "solution" $(1,1)$ (to be computed despite don't satisfy the requirements of this post), gives $k=13$ (there was a kind of "change of coordinates" if we can say so).